# How do you affect object transforms with nodes?

Tags: animation, node-editor, pynodes

I'm new to writing new node systems, so bear with me, but how do you write nodes that affect the transform [matrix] of objects and maybe even data [vertices]?

I just need some help getting started.

Comment: take a look at the source code of the available Node based addons ( animation nodes and Sverchok )

Comment: @Chebhou funny how I JUST discovered animation nodes right before checking back here for a response. Thanks! It's amazing that someone has been at the very thing I was going to make from scratch years ago.

Comment: after doing some reading it would useful for others and as future reference to write an answer with what you find out

Comment: @Chebhou That's the idea :) But, first, I have to get my head around all of this. Doesn't look too hard, right now.